# How to implement mergesort using F#

Tags: .net, algorithm, sorting, f#, mergesort

I need to implement merge-sort using F#, For that, I need 2 auxiliary functions: split and merge, where "split" splits a list in two smaller lists whose size differ by at most 1. I' m trying to create the split function. Here is the merge and split function I implemented so far:

```
let rec merge (l: 'a list, m: 'a list)=
    match l,m with
    |[],[] -> []
    |[],mi::mf -> mi::mf
    |li::lf,[] -> li::lf
    |li::lf, mi::mf -> if li<mi then li::merge (lf,mi::mf)
                       else mi::merge(li::lf,mf)


   let split (l: 'a list)=
        let n= l.Length
        if n%2=1 then
            for i in  1..n/2 do

let rec mergesort (l :'a list)=
    let (left,right)=split l
    if left.Length>1 || right.Length>1 then 
        merge(mergesort left,mergesort right)
    else
        merge(left,right)
```

I'm stuck, I don't know how to use pattern matching to go through the list to complete the split function. I also am not sure if mergesort is correct given that split and merge is correct.

Additionally, In my partern matching cases, the list is eigher `[]` or `ai::af` So I'm a bit unsure, when we write `ai::af`to represent a list, is a1 equals to af if the list contains only one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how a naive `mergesort`implementation may look like:

```
let split list =
    let rec aux l acc1 acc2 =
        match l with
            | [] -> (acc1,acc2)
            | [x] -> (x::acc1,acc2)
            | x::y::tail ->
                aux tail (x::acc1) (y::acc2)
    in aux list [] []

let rec merge l1 l2 = // this version is NOT tail-recursive
    match (l1,l2) with
        | (x,[]) -> x
        | ([],y) -> y
        | (x::tx,y::ty) ->
            if x <= y then x::merge tx l2
            else y::merge l1 ty

let rec mergesort list = 
    match list with
        | [] -> []
        | [x] -> [x]
        | _ -> let (l1,l2) = split list
               in merge (mergesort l1) (mergesort l2)
```

Well-thought accurate pattern matching is the core of it.

The main part `mergesort` recursively applies splitting of lists of length more, than 1, and then merges splitted halves being sorted by self-application:

- for an empty argument, or a singleton it just echoes it as the result
- otherwise (last case of the pattern match) it uses `split` to halve the argument `list` into a tuple of "halves" lists `(l1,l2)` and then uses `merge` to combine the results of self-application to `l1` and `l2`.

`split` uses the auxiliary function `aux` that converts any list into a tuple of lists consisting of the same elements with lengths differing no more, than by 1.

Finally, `merge` (implemented above in straightforward, but apparently not tail-recursive manner) reassembles together the pair of lists performing the sorting per se. It uses combining arguments into a tuple internally to simplify the argument pattern matching to just 3 cases: `non-empty,empty`, `empty,non-empty`, and `non-empty,non-empty`.

It is not too difficult to make `merge` tail-recursive, I didn't do it for didactical reasons. You may find the tail-recursive version in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/geandbe/8492224).

Comment: Sorry, does x::y::tail means x and y are the first 2 elements in the list?

Comment: @mathnoob: sure, `1::2::[]` is [1;2]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `List.splitInto` instead of implementing your own split function.

```
let rec mergeSort lst =
    let rec merge = function 
        | l, [] -> l
        | [], l -> l
        | x::xs, y::ys -> if x < y 
                          then x :: merge (xs, y::ys)
                          else y :: merge (x::xs, ys)
    match List.splitInto 2 lst with
    | [l1;l2] ->  merge (mergeSort l1, mergeSort l2)
    | l -> List.concat l
```